# Uncaught TypeError: three__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Float32Array is not a constructor

Tags: arrays, three.js

For some reason I get an error above for the following code:

```js
const parameters = {}
parameters.count = 1000



const generateGalaxy = () => {

    const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry()

    const positions = new THREE.Float32Array(parameters.count*3)



    for(let i=0; i < parameters.count; i++ ) {

        const i3 = i*3

        positions[i3] = Math.random()
        positions[i3 + 1] = Math.random()
        positions[i3 + 2] = Math.random()


    }

    geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3))
}

generateGalaxy()
```

The part that confuses me the most is when I used the exact same steps for making particles, I didn't get any error saying that Float32Array isn't a constructor. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`THREE.Float32Array` does not exist in three.js.

Change the line to be:

```js
const positions = new Float32Array(parameters.count*3)
```

...and the function should work fine.

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote and it worked the first time I used it, I was following a tutorial, I didn't think of the code by myself

Comment: @Coccinelle I have updated my answer. I was looking at it from the wrong direction. If the code you posted was from a tutorial, it either had a typo (and should NOT have worked), or it added `THREE.Float32Array = Float32Array`, which we could not have known.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you for the input